# My site looks like the desktop site on mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm not much of a UI developer so no matter how I ask this question it's going to sound stupid.

I created a simple site http://xAbout.com which looks fine on a PC screen, but does seem very mobile friendly.

I would have thought that Bootstrap 3 out of the box would have helped out here, but really what's displayed on the mobile device (Android) is just a shrunken version. What am I missing here?

Comment: Read the docs. You're missing the meta viewport tag and you also have many errors in your html. you don't close the link rel="stylesheet"

Comment: Use [the HTML5 validator](http://html5.validator.nu/) and then also [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint#in-the-browser)